# Apache2 serve multiple laravel project

Tags: laravel, apache2, ubuntu-server

I have an ubuntu 22.04 webserver on which i have configured php, mariadb, apache2 stack.
I then deployed a laravel project, which works fine, under the path.
`/var/www/html/site1.it`

So now I created a project under the path `/var/www/html/site2.it` and re-executed the same steps done for site1.
So I created the site2.conf, entered the configuration and restarted apache2.
On my mac in the hosts file I then set the IP <-> site pair to reach the site via domain.
However, when I type the url `http://site2.it` on the browser, I call site1.it

Do you have any suggestions or advice?

EDIT: Steps to configure Apache2 site

I've followed this tutorial:
[Deploy Laravel on Apache server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-22-04)

- apache site1.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin site1@localhost
    ServerName site1
    ServerAlias site1.it
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.it/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site1.it [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =site1
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
#<VirtualHost *:443>
 #    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.it/public
 #    ServerName site1
 #    ServerAlias www.site1.it
 #    SSLEngine on
 #    SSLCertificateFile /home/
 #    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home
 #
 #    <Directory /var/www/html/site1.it/public>
 #        Order allow,deny
 #        AllowOverride All
 #        Allow from all
 #    </Directory>
#</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What are the steps you followed for `/var/www/html/site1.it`

Comment: Hi, edited the question with steps.